# how to create a MySQL / PHP sub query to count the number of records matching a value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am having trouble querying MySQL. I want to actually get the count of records with the value of the current `parent_cat_id`. So in this case we want a sub_query that will tell us 4 (because there are 4

```
id  parent_cat_id   cat_name                                        
6   2   Carrot                                      
8   2   Potatoes                                        
7   2   Lettuce                                     
13  2   Asparagus                                       
4   1   Pears                                       
3   1   Banannas                                        
2   1   Apples
```

the Main $query which produces what I posted and much more information which I will use....

```
$menu_query = "SELECT c.id AS id, parent_cat_id, cat_name FROM db.category c JOIN db.parent_category pc ON pc.id = c.parent_cat_id WHERE c.is_active = 1 AND c.is_menu = 1 ORDER BY pc.sort_order, c.sort_order;";

$menu_result = mysql_query($menu_query) or die(mysql_error());

while($menu_row = mysql_fetch_array($menu_result)){
    $menu_name = $menu_row['cat_name'];
    $id = $menu_row['id'];
    $parent_cat_id = $menu_row['parent_cat_id'];
            #echo $parent_cat_id;
    #return from database the $count of  records with the same  ['parent_cat_id'] 's
```

So I was hoping for a $sub_query of some sort so that I know in my php code to build the next menu's items. The first menu should have 4 and the second menu should have 3.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** FINAL WORKING SUB QUERY

```
SELECT c.id AS category_id, c.parent_cat_id, cat_name, d.totalCount 
FROM category c 
INNER JOIN parent_category pc 
ON pc.id = c.parent_cat_id 
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT parent_cat_id, COUNT(*) totalCount 
    FROM category 
    WHERE is_menu = 1 
    AND parent_cat_id = 2 
    ORDER BY parent_cat_id 
) d 
ON c.parent_cat_id = d.parent_cat_id 
WHERE c.is_active = 1 
AND c.is_menu = 1 
ORDER BY pc.sort_order, c.sort_order;
```

Thanks again for your help!!!  I just needed to throw in another WHERE clause in the sub query you taught me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have extra subquery to count the values for each `parent_cat_id`

```
SELECT  c.id AS id,
        pc.parent_cat_id,
        pc.cat_name,
        d.totalCount
FROM    db.category c
        INNER JOIN db.parent_category pc
            ON pc.id = c.parent_cat_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT parent_cat_id, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM db.parent_category
            GROUP BY parent_cat_id
        ) d ON c.parent_cat_id = d.parent_cat_id
WHERE   c.is_active = 1 AND 
        c.is_menu = 1
ORDER   BY  pc.sort_order,
            c.sort_order
```

Comment: Hmm It is not running although I am trying =)  Should there be a d after the sub query line `FROM db.parent_category d ` ?? Thanks again!!

Comment: i'm sorry for the typo, yeah it should be `d` instead of `c`. i updated the answer.

Comment: Yes it does not work exactly, maybe because in the `parent_category` table there is only an `id` column and not a `parent_cat_id`? Thank you again, I will loook at it again after work tonight.